# Is there any third party component available for working with opeXML?

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, vsto, openxml

I want to some automation in word. i have lot of technique from VSTO side, but it takes long time for big size document.for that we are moving towards openxml.Please suggest me any third party component available for OPENXML.

Answer (score 1):

See [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) in MSDN for more information.

Also you may find third-party commercial components for the server-side execution. Don't want to advertise any there.

Comment: Thanks @Eugene 
I already known abt OPENXML SDK, I need instead of this, 
Can u suggest me

Comment: Take a look at Aspose.